# expand div height onmouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need height on the div 50px in default and it has to be changed to 300px onmouseover. I coded in below manner to implement it.

```
<style type="text/css">
#div1{
height:50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#div1:hover{
height:300px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

This code is working fine but as per CSS property on hover its immediately changing its height. Now, I need a stylish way like slowly expanding div onmouseover and contracting onmoveout. How to expand and contract div on hover?

Comment: You could use jquery. Using the animate function. See here http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Or you could use css transitions (when available).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few approaches -- here is CSS and Jquery, which should work in all browsers, not just modern ones:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#div1").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '+=250' //adds 250px
        }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '-=250px' //substracts 250px
        }, 'slow'
      );
    }
  );

});
</script> 

<style type="text/css">
#div1{
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: red; /* just for demo */
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="div1">This is div 1</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's better to read out the original height first, because if you are changing the height via CSS, you also need to re-edit the JS, which is not very practical (e.g. can be forgotten).

Comment: okay, in that case, the "height: '+=250'" should just be set to "height: '300px'"

Comment: hmm... seems to work in my demo.  i'm going to edit the code now to include the full jquery include, class, etc -- just put all of it into a blank HTML doc, and you should see it go.

Comment: @feeela, i adjusted the mouseout animation to just subtract 250px, again.  this way, the original CSS will dictate the start point.  still would have to edit the JS, if you wanted to go bigger than an additional 250px

Comment: if you just wanted to edit height in the CSS (more practical if you want this to be a DRY type of function), then you'd want to animate jQuery's addClass() or toggleClass() functions -- that's a bit more work, though.

Comment: @Dustin If you don't go for the pure-CSS-version suggested by j-man86, one shouldn't hide the block using CSS, but setting the initial height via JS too. That way you can read out the used height first, hide the bottom part and display it again on mouse-hover – that's called ["unobtrusive JavaScript"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: @Dustin Here is a concept on how that might work: http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/Lw3CE/3/  (Well, it has some problems in Opera, but I didn't want to spend any more time on that)

Comment: @Dustin - How can I slow down the sliding speed. I tried changing 'slow' to '10000' but it didn't work. :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  Given that IE7, IE8, and IE9 are around, it's good to have a solution that works in all browsers.

Answer (score 5):

```
#div1{
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Easy!

Comment: Wow! awesome! but how can I decrease the sliding speed?

Comment: increase .3s to 1s for example

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before asking you but didn't find great difference when changed from 3 to 10 that's why I asked! Anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: you should note that css transitions are restricted for new'ish browsers anyway.

Comment: Yeah! that's the issue. Better I will opt for jQuery! which has cross browser support.

Comment: You should check the browser support in your region of the world.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

I wouldn't be surprised if in a year no one is using IE8. If almost all of South America uses Chrome and Russia uses Firefox, when will China, the Middle East, U.S, Canada, and the rest of the world catch up?

Only as long as we as web designers continue to support IE will people be dependent on it.

Answer (score 3):

In a "modern" browser, you can just apply a `css transition effect`:

```
#div1 {
    -moz-transition: 4s all ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: 4s all ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 4s all ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 4s all ease-in-out;
}
```

This would apply a transition effect over 4 seconds with a `ease-in-out` easing for compatible firefox, ie, chrome/safari (webkit) and opera browser. Read more:

[CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions)

You can take this one step ahead and check if the current browser supports css transitions, if available, use them for animation and if not use a javascript animation script. Example for that:

[BarFoos animations](https://github.com/jAndreas/BarFoos/blob/master/development/plugins/core_plugin_dommanipulation.js#L298)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `.animate()` This will act on any element with with a class of "tab", and will revert on mouse-out.

```
$('.tab').hover(function() {
     $(this).stop()
     $(this).animate({
        height: '+=250'
      }, 500)

         }, function() {
    $(this).stop()
     $(this).animate({
        height: '-=250'
      }, 500)            
})
```

Comment: Thanks! this code works fine but its executing on PageLoad. How to execute this code onmouseover? I am sorry to ask this kind of silly question but I don't know how to code in jQuery!

Comment: Sorry to say! this didn't work. I tried as `<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.tab').hover(function() {
     $(this).stop()
     $(this).animate({
        height: '+=200'
      }, 500});
   },
  $(this).stop()     
  $(this).animate({
        height: '-=200'
      }, 500});
})
});
</script>` and as you said I modified div as <div id="div1" class="tab"></div>

Comment: There is a problem in this code. In your fiddle itself try making a hover again when its sliding. Its bit tricky but try to make another hover when slideup/slidedown is taking place. You will understand the issue.

Comment: Diodeus, how can I use the above code (The code I marked as answer) to execute if hover is kept for 5 continuous seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's `.mouseover` http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/, `.mouseout` http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/, and `.animate` http://api.jquery.com/animate/ to perform that.

On the `.mouseover` event, you would animate the height to be 300px, and on the `.mouseout` event you would animate to 50px.  Make sure you call `.stop` on the div before you call animate, otherwise you will have odd issues.